# how to get length of string [] []

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2D array of string defined as

```
string[][] input_data;
```

I can count the number of rows by `input_data.GetLength(0)`
but if I use `input_data.GetLength(1)` to get number of column, I always get

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>     Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Array.GetLength(Int32 dimension)
>          ...

I also noticed that at debugging, when I hover my mouse on my array (after all the data has been inserted) it only shows the first value (number of row) like this: `input_data| {string[18][]}`, if I continue expand the array then it shows all the 18 row data with the column data, like this:

[image]

How do I get the number of column? (in this case it is 139)

Comment: I don't think ToArray works like that with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Have you tried input_data[0].getLength(0)?

Comment: I don't see variable "data" in your code

Comment: Msdn says that this exception occur when `dimension is equal to or greater than Rank.` In your case `Rank=1`, because `ToArray` return 1 dimension array, despite the fact that its values are also an array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you posted is a jagged array, not a multi-dimensional array. It's a 1-D array that contains other arrays. There is no second dimension so you can't use `data.GetLength(1)`. Each row can have a different number of columns.

You can get the minimum or maximum number of columns for each row with    `data.Max(r=>r.Length)` or `data.Min(r=>r.Length)`, eg:

```
var s=new string[][]{
    new[] {"a","b"},
    new[] {"a"}
};

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",s.Max(r=>r.Length),s.Min(r=>r.Length));
```

will print

```
2 1
```

To specify a multi-dimensional array, you need to use the `[,]` syntax:

```
var s=new string[,]{
    {"a","b"},
    {"c","d"},
    {"e","f"}
};

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",s.GetLength(0),s.GetLength(1));
```

This will return :

```
3 2
```

Answer (score 3):

GetLength(1) would work if you had a multidimensional array:

```
string[,] input_data = new string[27,139];
var columns = input_data.GetLength(1);
```

What you have now is a jagged array not a 2D array, so there is no guarantee that all items ('rows') have the same number of elements ('columns'). 
However in case you can't use multidimensional array for some reason and you are sure that the input will be that way you can use the length of the first element input_data[0].Length

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing an array of arrays and a multi dimentional array, run this code :

```
    string[][] array_of_arrays = new string[5][];
    Console.WriteLine(array_of_arrays.Length);
    array_of_arrays[0] = new string[5];
    array_of_arrays[1] = new string[6];
    Console.WriteLine(array_of_arrays[0].Length);
    Console.WriteLine(array_of_arrays[1].Length);
    string[,] multi_d_array = new string[4,2];
    Console.WriteLine(multi_d_array.GetLength(0));
    Console.WriteLine(multi_d_array.GetLength(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a jagged array. You can get the first dimensions size as 'input_data.GetLength(0)' and second dimension size as 'input_data.GetLength(1)'. Try it

Example:

```
string[,] input_data = new string[5,12];
var column1 = input_data.GetLength(0);
var column2 = input_data.GetLength(1);
```